# xml to mysql database

Tags: mysql, xml

I have a question. Does anyone have a working php script which can parse a XML file to a sql database? I have searched for some scripts and didn't find anything what looks like I can edit it to my needs.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Parse the XML using [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php) and extract the data of your interest from the XML file and insert into MySql using functions listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).

Give it a try. Its not that difficult and you'll learn a lot.

Comment: haha.. I dont know how to do this, isn't there a program what can help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a PHP solution, but you can extract values from XML directly into mySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html

Of course, if this is something you will need to do often, you can always fall back to what bzabhi have said.

Comment: Actually, this does have PHP code to parse the XML file. Heh.

Answer (score -1):

Why not write one from scratch? Not that hard.

Comment: I guess a couple of pointers as to how to do this wouldn't have gone amiss here ;-)

Comment: Recommend a tutorial "XPath in SimpleXML" at http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/09/30/xpath-in-simplexml/.

You can parse an XML file with regex instead of XPath if you like.

After parsing the XML with XPath or regex, you can design a database table according to the relevant fields and import the extracted fields into the table.